# Perl Array Order

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting, dictionary

I'am new with perl and stucked with the following exercise.
I have a multi-array and want order its element to descending to the inside arrays sum's.
I want to make the order with Schwartzian transform.

This is my vector:

```
my @vectors = ( [1], [ 1, 2, 3 ], [4], [ 2, 2, 1 ] );
```

This is the expected vector:

```
@sorted_vectors = ( [1,2,3], [2,2,1], [4], [1] );
```

So far I am tried with these:

(1)
    #!/usr/bin/perl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my @vectors = ( [1], [ 1, 2, 3 ], [4], [ 2, 2, 1 ] );

my @sorted_vectors;

  # @sorted_vectors = ( [1,2,3], [2,2,1], [4], [1] );


my %hash=();
for(my $i=0;$i< scalar @vectors;$i++){

$hash{$i}=@vectors[$i];
}


for my $key ( sort { $hash{$b}[1] <=> $hash{$a}[1] } keys %hash ) {
    push(@sorted_vectors,[@{$hash{$key}}]);
}

 print Dumper( \@sorted_vectors );
```

(2)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my @vectors = ( [1], [ 1, 2, 3 ], [4], [ 2, 2, 1 ] );

my @sorted_vectors;

  # @sorted_vectors = ( [1,2,3], [2,2,1], [4], [1] );


my @sorted = map  { $_->[0] }
          sort { $a->[1] cmp $b->[1] }
          map  { [$_, foo($_)] }
               @vectors;

sub foo{
    my $res = 0;
    foreach my $x (@_) {
        $res+= $x;
    }
    return $res;

}

 print Dumper(\@sorted);
```

Comment: You'll want to change that `cmp` to `<=>` as you're comparing numbers. The `cmp` will only work as long as your totals are less than 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works with few alterations,

```
my @sorted = map  { $_->[0] }
      # sort { $a->[1] cmp $b->[1] } # string sort, ascending order
      sort { $b->[1] <=> $a->[1] }   # numeric sort, descending order
      # map  { [$_, foo($_)] }       # foo() expects list, not array reference
      map  { [$_, foo(@$_)] }        # dereferencing $_ aref for foo()
           @vectors;
```

or same thing but using `sum()` from core module [`List::Util`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util#sum)

```
use List::Util 'sum';
my @vectors = ( [1], [ 1, 2, 3 ], [4], [ 2, 2, 1 ] );

my @sorted_vectors = map $_->[0],
    sort { $b->[1] <=> $a->[1] }
    map [ $_, sum(@$_) ],
    @vectors;

use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \@sorted_vectors;
```

output

```
$VAR1 = [
      [
        1,
        2,
        3
      ],
      [
        2,
        2,
        1
      ],
      [
        4
      ],
      [
        1
      ]
    ];
```

Comment: `use List::Util 'sum';
    my @sorted = sort { sum( @$b ) <=> sum( @$a ) } @vectors ;`

Comment: @Zaid yes correct, note only that OP insisted on using ST.

Comment: See also `List::UtilsBy::nsort_by`, as per my answer

Comment: @LeoNerd +1 it is a shame that sort of utils isn't merged and in the core by now (always wanted max_by, min_by).

Comment: @mpapec: I maintain List::Util in core, so I'm open to suggestions for moving.

Comment: @LeoNerd yes I'm aware of that, appreciate your effort. I was referring to [merging](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/PEVANS/List-UtilsBy-0.09/lib/List/UtilsBy.pm#TODO) `List::UtilsBy` with `List::Utils` and thus making List::UtilsBy methods available in perl core modules?

Answer (score 1):

This is simple with `List::UtilsBy::rev_nsort_by` and `List::Util::sum`:

```
my @vectors = ( [1], [ 1, 2, 3 ], [4], [ 2, 2, 1 ] );

my @sorted = rev_nsort_by { sum @$_ } @vectors;
```

This sorts the list of `@vectors` in reverse numerical order (i.e. largest number first) of the result of its control block. The control block here simply sums all the individual elements of each component.